# Jsonify a Jdbc4Array in Clojure

Tags: json, postgresql, clojure

I want to jsonify the results of a query performed against a Postgres table containing a column of type `text[]`, but the problem is that `clojure.data.json.write-str` doesn't seem to know how to handle PG arrays:

> Exception Don't know how to write JSON of class org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array  clojure.data.json/write-generic

Do I have to supply a custom handler, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to wrap up, here's what works for me, putting together Jared's answer with the latest `clojure.java.jdbc` API changes (0.3.0-alpha5 at the time of writing) which deprecate some patterns that are commonly used (e.g. `with-query-results`).

First define additional handlers for every unsupported types you care about, for instance:

```
(extend-type org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array
  json/JSONWriter
  (-write [o out]
    (json/-write (.getArray o) out)))

(extend-type java.sql.Timestamp
  json/JSONWriter
  (-write [date out]
    (json/-write (str date) out)))
```

Then use `with-open` to perform the JSON encoding while the connection is still open (which is important at least for `org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array`):

```
(with-open [conn (jdbc/get-connection db)]
   (json/write-str
     (jdbc/query {:connection conn}
                 ["SELECT * FROM ..."]))))
```

I guess this will change as the `clojure.java.jdbc` API evolves, but for the moment, it works.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to extend `IResultSetReadColumn` because you are not
required to stay in the scope of `with-open`

Something along the following is also more concise:

```
(extend-protocol jdbc/IResultSetReadColumn
  org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array 
  (result-set-read-column [pgobj metadata idx]
    (.getArray pgobj)))
```

Make sure the namespace where this is placed-in is required!

Answer (score 1):

[cheshire](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire) is good about handling various data types and being extensible (see add-encoder)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is `org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array` does not implement `java.util.Collection`. Try calling [`getArray`](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/jdbc4/Jdbc4Array.html#getArray%28long,%20int,%20java.util.Map%29) before you serialize it.

Edit:

If it is a nested structure, then it might be best to implement a handler. `clojure.data.json` uses the [`JSONWriter`](https://github.com/clojure/data.json/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/data/json.clj#L284) protocol. You can try something like the following:

```
;; Note: Pseudo Code
(extend-type org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Array
  clojure.data.json/JSONWriter
  (-write [o out] (clojure.data.json/-write (.getArray o) out)))
```

Comment: Yes but since this is a substructure (i.e. one of the row fields), how would you do that?

Comment: Then a handler might be your best option

Comment: Thanks, this seems a good solution, unfortunately it yields "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed." (without any additional useful error message), any idea why?

Comment: I believe you have to use `getArray` before the connection is closed.

Comment: Ok thanks, but since your suggestions are slightly above my current "Clojure comfort zone", I will have to study it a bit before I can tell if it works.

Comment: The problem is that the clojure.java.jdbc API has been recently updated, and the "with-connection + with-query-results" pattern deprecated in favor of a simpler "query" one, with which I really don't know how to do anything "before the connection is closed".